# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_value'

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

I receive the `AttributeError` only after the value is successfully deleted - Please suggest if there is anything wrong in the way the values are printed. The function prints correctly prior to a Delete

```
 class Node:
        def __init__(self, value=None, l_next=None):
            self.value = value
            self.l_next = l_next

        def get_value(self):
            return self.value

        def set_value(self, val):
            self.value = val

        def get_next_node(self):
            return self.l_next

        def set_next_node(self, n_next):
            self.l_next = n_next


    class LinkedList:
        def __init__(self, head=None):
            self.head = head

        def add_node(self, value):
            new_node = Node(value, self.head)
            self.head = new_node

        def find_node(self, value):
            curr = self.head
            while curr:
                if curr.get_value() == value:
                    return True
                curr = curr.get_next_node()
            return False

        def del_node(self, val):
            curr = self.head
            prev = None
            while curr:
                if curr.get_value() == val:
                    if prev:
                        prev.set_next_node(curr.get_next_node)
                    else:
                        self.head = curr.get_next_node
                    print("Item Deleted")
                    return True
                prev = curr
                curr = curr.get_next_node()
            print("Item not available for Delete")
            return False

        def print_list(self):
            item_list = []
            curr = self.head
            while curr:
                item_list.append(curr.get_value())
                curr = curr.get_next_node()
            return item_list


    List1 = LinkedList()
    List1.add_node(4)
    List1.add_node(5)
    List1.add_node(1)
    List1.add_node(19)
    List1.add_node(41)
    List1.add_node(25)
    List1.add_node(40)
    List1.add_node(51)
    print(List1.print_list())
    print(List1.find_node(20))
    print(List1.find_node(5))
    List1.del_node(20)
    List1.del_node(5)
    print(List1.print_list())
```

Output :

```
[51, 40, 25, 41, 19, 1, 5, 4]
False
True
Item not available for Delete
Item Deleted
```

Error:

```
print(List1.print_list())
File "C:/Users/sv4/PycharmProjects/Sample/LinkedList.py", line 55, in 
print_list
item_list.append(curr.get_value())
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_value'      
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: In `del_node`, you use `curr.get_next_node` instead of `curr.get_next_node()` a few times: e.g. `self.head = curr.get_next_node`

Comment: Thanks Patrick , I was looking into the print_list() function for missing parenthesis. I fixed the del_node and its working fine